# How can I connect an ADC8686S to an Arduino Mega using SPI?

Tags: arduino, spi, adc, teensy

I am trying to connect a TI ADC8686S (datasheet [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8686s.pdf?ts=1710391902842&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)) to an Arduino Mega 2560 Rev3

I use the following code

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>

const int CSPin = 53;

static int registerAdress = 0x10 << 9;
static int write_read_bit = 0 << 15;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(CSPin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CSPin,HIGH);
  SPI.begin();

}

void loop() {
  int result;
  digitalWrite(CSPin,LOW);
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(10 * 1000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0)); //frequency in kHz
  result = SPI.transfer16(write_read_bit + registerAdress);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  digitalWrite(CSPin,HIGH);
  Serial.println("Data read on SDOA = "+result);

}
```

I communicate with the ADC with SPI, with the following pinout.

| Arduino Mega | ADC8686S |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | SDOA |
| 51 | DB10/SDI |
| 52 | SCLK |
| 53 | CS |

I power the AVDD and DVDD with 5V, DB9/BYTESEL is LOW, SER/BYTE/PAR is HIGH. Firstly, I power all my setup on, then I manually connect the RESET pin to 0V to initiate a full reset for a few seconds. Here is the output of the logic analyzer I use to monitor my setup.
[Here is the output of the logic analyzer I use to monitor my setup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3uDX.png) I have also zoomed on data exchanges [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoGNG.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEvAt.png). My input command should read the value of the 0x10 register, but I obtain different values at each time. Is my setup correct (I have supposed CPOL=0 and CPHA=0 but I am not sure)? Is it normal that I have such different output values for the same register ? Is my ADC working correctly ?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: 1) On Q1, read the datahseet (search SPI frequency). 2) On Q2, you didn't call SPI.begin() to initialize the SPI, nor calling SPI.beginTransaction() and SPI.endTransaction(), so read the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/spi/begintransaction/) first. 3) If you are new in using the sensor, the easier way is to check the register map (hint: 7.6 Register Maps on datasheet) to see what is the most simple register that you could communicate with to ensure that the code you wrote work with the device, i.e. read the `Device_ID` of the sensor.